# how to insert 0 (false) into bit field in phpmyadmin sql table using Volley in android

Tags: mysql

I am trying to put String "0" in the parameter but in the table i`m getting 1 in the specified column.

in php script i have this code: (i removed the irrelevant code)

```
$isRegistered= $_POST['isRegistered']; 

$sql = "INSERT INTO Users (isRegistered) VALUES ('$isRegistered')";
```

in my java code i have: (i removed the irrelevant code)

```
private static final String USER_IS_REGISTERED = "isRegistered";
private static final String FALSE = "0";


        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_LINK,

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put(USER_IS_REGISTERED,FALSE);
                return params;
            }
        };
```

Comment: Your question is wrong. Has nothing to do with Volley. The database actions are done by php. So first find out how you do it in php. You should not try to insert a string "0" in a field where a boolean valur `true` or `false` is expected.

Comment: Well that is what i think that it should be boolean. But i can not see your definition of the field. Maybe you have to place an integer 0 or 1. Only you know.

Comment: @greenapps the reason i included it as a volley problem is because i cant put boolean value in the parameters, maybe it has something to do with this

Comment: You cannot put integers in them either. Only text. It does not matter what you put in a parameter on android side. Just send something. Something for true and something for false. These will be strings both. In your php script check what you receive and then set a true or false. But not the received string.